# How to get textbox helper to display valid HTML markup for HTML 4.01 strict?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following code in my page/view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50" })
```

The output generated is:

```
<input id="Name" maxlength="50" name="Name" size="50" type="text" value="" />
```

I am using the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

My page is not validating using the HTML validation tool because of the closing /> of the input element.  How do I get the helper to create me an input element looking like:

```
<input id="Name" maxlength="50" name="Name" size="50" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that html generated by `TextBoxFor` helper is correct or at least can be used in any browser, but if you want to create your own helper method, you can add a extension method to the `HtmlHelper`. For example:

```
public static class MyExtension
{
  public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBox(this HtmlHelper html, string var1, string var2)
  {
     StringBuilder tag= new StringBuilder();
     // create your tag and wrtite it in string buffer
     return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html generated by HTML helpers is XHTML valid and difference between HTML 4.01 strict and XHTML is that XHTML requires empty elements (as input, br, link, etc.) to close as in xml.
I think that XHTML is more current standard and if there are no specific limitations you should use it, one of the reasons would be, that you HTML in such case can be used as XML (for XSLT processing and so on).

Comment: I am using the YUI controls and they recommend using 4.01 strict.  So I would like to keep it this way throughout the whole project.

Comment: Hm, i find that strange, do you have link, where this is written?

Comment: Yes, go to http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2.  Everything is strict 4.01.  Go and look for example at the grids.

Comment: I don't have a great link for html5 and web is full of average links for it. Anyway, if it is a new project, why you're using YUI 2? Because I think they won't support YUI 2 anymore, so in case there are any bugs in it, you'll be stuck.

Comment: I like YUI2, YUI3 doesn't have all the controls that I need, like buttons, treview, etc.  They also do strict.  What are you suggesting then?

Comment: I think there's 4 ways: rewrite all html helpers (well, not fun way), use xhtml and hope that yui 2 will deal with it (it should be more or less ok with it), post process rendered views (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783721/asp-net-mvc-view-post-processing, I may be would do it on EndRequest event) or use different set of controls (telerik is nice)

Answer (score 0):

Html helpers in asp.net mvc are just the *helpers* that simplify html generation process. They do not include anything magical behind them, just render html. If you want to have absolute control over generated html, you can create your own helpers or **write the pure html in your view**. There's nothing wrong about that.

By the way, asp.net mvc 3 by default uses `data-*` attributes that are part of html5. If you absolutely do not wish to use them, turn off in web.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Just for interests sake, why do you refer to the data-* attributes here?

Comment: One more point that makes asp.net-mvc 3 incompatible with html 4. If you use any kind of default validation on x.Name, you get those attributes on generated html

Comment: Can you give me some more sample code on what you are describing above?  And with the data stuff?

Comment: Put the [Required] attribute on Name property of your model. And then take a look at what html it generates. Of course, if you are using asp.net-mvc3

Comment: I use fluent validation.  Will it do the same?